# Should separate tags be created for spin-offs?

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

I created a question about Fairy Tail Zero, thus tagged it appropriately and additionally tried to edit the [fairy-tail-zero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tail-zero) tag, adding some information. But as I was adding the information, all I could really do is link to Fairy Tail's main sites. So this made me wonder whether it really needs its own tag and more general, whether spin-offs should have their own tag?

Comment: generally I think we stick to the main series tag, unless it's significantly different. There's another meta post somewhere I'll look for - this is an old one, but i'll check again for something newer http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-multiple-continuities-have-individual-tags?lq=1